# How can I ensure that a minimal set of processes are running on ubuntu 11.10

Tags: process, background-process

I'm running experiments via python & pygame that are time-sensitive and I'd like to reduce all the OS's background processing as much as possible while still being able to do things like detect keyboard/gamepad/mouse input, show things on screen, and play sounds. How could I go about killing all superfluous processes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using nice? that may be enough for your needs.

```
sudo nice -20 your-program.py
```

this will ensure that your program has a higher priority than other processes.

Comment: If I'm using a python package like pygame that uses lower level libraries (e.g. pygame uses SDL), will this prioritize the computation done by those lower level libraries as well?

Comment: It should, unless you fork or do something to make it effectively become another process.

Comment: hm, I do use the multiprocessing library to create separate but intercommunicating processes. Hopefully calling os.nice(-20) in each separate process will set them all to equal-and-highest priority (?)

Comment: yes, calling it on each process would work, but I suggest you read up on nice and process scheduling to ensure that setting them to -20 does what you want; you may end up with a lot of processes fighting each other for CPU.